# Simplify the HTML tags?

Tags: html, css

I hope you are well.

Im really struggling to simplify the HTML below, I was wondering if you can help me to do so?, I do still want to keep the output as presented code, however I think their are too many lines and tags.

I hope you can advise, really new to HTML.

```
<div>
<span style="font-size:medium; text-indent:0px; -webkit-text-stroke-width:0px">
<span style="font-size:14px">
<span style="font-family:&quot;Segoe UI Semilight&quot;">
<span style="line-height:normal">
<span style="font-family:&quot;Segoe UI Semilight&quot;, sans-serif"><span style="color:#005ad2">I need the support</span></span>
</span>
</span>
</span>
<br>
<span style="font-size:14px">
<span style="font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;">If you believe your issue is not resolved, via&nbsp;
</span>
</span>
<a href="https://google.co.uk/" style="font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;, sans-serif; font-size:10.5pt">Google Online</a>
<span style="font-size:12pt">
<span style="font-family:&quot;Segoe UI&quot;, sans-serif">.</span>
</span>
</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an easy implementation where I've separated the styles from the HTML, you can add the styles to your HTML page by enclosing it in `<style></style>` tags

```css
.span1 {
  font-size: medium;
  text-indent: 0px;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI Semilight", sans-serif;
  line-height: normal;
  color: #005ad2;
}

.text1 {
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Segoe UI";
}

.link {
  font-family:"Segoe UI&quot",sans-serif;
  font-size:10.5pt;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <span class="span1">
    I need the support
  </span>
  <br>
  <span class="text1">
    If you believe your issue is not resolved, via&nbsp;
  </span>
  <a href="https://google.co.uk/"class="link">Google Online</a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3):

Okay. I see you are using too many span elements and using `<br/>` elements to break the line, which although will render but is not quite an efficient thing to do. What I would suggest, you should use `div` element where you think you will break the line, so wrap that content in a div element because `div` elements are by default `block` elements and `span` elements are by default `inline` elements. Here is my [suggestion](https://codepen.io/Jamsshhayd/pen/xxwJREY) in implementation.

```css
.blue {
  color:#005ad2;
}
.font10pt {
    font-size: 10.5pt !important;
}
.defaultClass {
  text-indent: 0px;
  font-size: 14px !important;
  font-family: "Segoe UI Semilight", sans-serif;
  line-height: normal;
  font-size: medium;
  -webkit-text-stroke-width:0px;
}
```

```html
<div class='defaultClass'>
  <div class='blue'>
      I need the support
  </div>
  If you believe your issue is not resolved, via 
  <a href="https://google.co.uk/" class='font10pt'>Google Online.</a>
</div>
```

PS: Keeping things in the tags is a better approach then to keep the text raw in the page. Such as I have placed *"If you believe your issue is not resolved, via"* this line and the `<a>` element side by side, but it would be better if you wrap it inside a `<span>` element so you know for sure that this text would be rendered as inline text with the anchor element.

Happy coding!

Answer (score 1):

When using several styles in one element, it can help readability and organisation to place styles in the `<style>` tags within the `<head>`, rather than nesting elements for the purpose of styling.

```
<head>
<style>
    .text1 {
        text-indent: 0;
        -webkit-text-stroke-width: 0;
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI Semilight';
        line-height: normal;
        color:#005ad2
    }
    .text2 {
        font-size: 14px;
        font-family: 'Segoe UI Semilight, sans-serif';
        line-height: normal;
        color: #005ad2
    }
    .text3 {
        font-family: 'Segoe UI Semilight, sans-serif';
        font-size: 10.5pt;
    }
    .text4 {
        font-family: 'Segoe UI Semilight, sans-serif';
        font-size: 12pt;
    }
</style>
</head>

<body>
<div>
    <span class="text1">I need the support</span>
    <br>
    <span class="text2">If you believe your issue is not resolved, via&nbsp;</span>
    <a class="text3" href="https://google.co.uk/"></a>
    <span class="text4">.</span>
</div>
</body>
```